# DKIM Selector -- Are they unique? or can a random selector be used.

Tags: domain-name-system, email, dkim

I am setting up my DNS records with two email services:

1st G suite and the 2nd is active trail

When setting my DKIM selector for G suite I have read it is google, however I have not been provided the selector for active trail.

Can I set a random selector or will it impact email deliverability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a random selector, although you can use a random string as the selector name when you publish it.  While you should change your selector periodically, its name is fixed for its lifetime.  (Keep the old selector active when adding a new selector.)

For each selector you need a signing (private) key and a public key.  The public key is published using the selector as a domain name.  I described creating and publishing the keys in my my blog post on [Implementing DKIM with Exim](http://9https://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-dkim-with-exim/).

It is not necessary to sign your mail, but it is a good idea.  Many domains do not sign their content, and many that do fail to correctly publish the selector record.  Configure a DMARC policy record to define you policy and abide by it.

Comment: Why should the DKM selector be changed periodically?